# изменить название свойства объекта

Tags: javascript, объекты

подкажите как менять название свойства объекта ? например есть глубокий объект и я хочу поменять не значение свойства а и менно название самого свойства `const obj = { name: "alex", iq: 10, other: { a: 1, b: 2,  } }` Например я хочу изменить b на c , т.е. как бы переименовать.

Comment: Такой возможности нет. Вы можете получить значение нужного вам свойства, удалить свойство и добавить новое свойство с сохраненным значением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По мотивам комментария, исходя из условий вопроса:

```js
function fChangeKeyName(pathKey, oldNameKey, newNameKey) {
  pathKey[newNameKey] = pathKey[oldNameKey];
  delete pathKey[oldNameKey];
}

const obj = { name: "alex", iq: 10, other: { a: 1, b: 2 } };
console.log("Исходный объект", obj);

fChangeKeyName(obj.other, "b", "c");
console.log("Изменённый объект", obj);
```